# XWiki convert to uppercase macro

Tags: string, xwiki

I need to convert the results of other macros to uppercase. Something like,

```
{{caps}}<Some macros>{{/caps}}
```

Catch is that I can't use XWiki programming scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CSS:

```
text-transform: uppercase;
```

just identify the CSS generated class.

Answer (score 1):

Could you clarify what you mean by `<some macro>` and give an example? There are several types of macros in XWiki.

If you mean another rendering macro of the type `{{somemacro/}}` then it's not easy. You'd need to parse the content as wiki syntax with an XWiki Syntax parser and then execute the Macro Transformation and then from the XDOM, render it using a plain text renderer for example, then convert to uppercase and then regenerate an XDOM out of it (by parsing it using the plain text parser for example).

Hope it helps